# How to extract data from online available database API into firebase database without actually creating database?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to flutter, firebase, and using APIs. I am working on a travel guide app. I want to do add a database for hotels, flights, and places to visit without actually creating the database myself. I thought using API is a good option. But I do not know how to extract data from the online available database API into the firebase database. I even researched a lot about it but I didn't get a very satisfying result.
I did the complete authentication part, but I do not know how to proceed further. So, could anyone please help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, it is possible. You can use Firebase without initializing the databases. You can use `Callable Cloud Functions` to pass through your app requests to the Hotel API-s. You could use `Remote-Config` for some configuration data...

**BUT**: I can't imagine an App that you plan without at least some data to be saved into one of the databases. You can also use Firebase in combination with other databases from other providers and services.

You can use most of the Firebase Services like Auth, Hosting, and Databases without using others. You can also use Firebase just for Auth or just for Hosting.